# How to get the h2 with the specific a tag underneath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dom, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website. That is the structure of the page:

```html
<h2>AFRICA (54)</h2>
<ul>
    <li> <a href="https://www.worldatlas.com/webimage/countrys/africa/dz.htm">Algeria</a> *54
</ul>
```

and this code structure goes on 6 times. Because it has 6 continents. My problem is that I get all the `a` tags, but I just want the text of the `a` tag underneath a `h2` tag.

That's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://www.worldatlas.com/cntycont.htm')
html_text = url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'lxml')

continent_name_resultset = soup.findAll('h2',limit=6)
country_name_resultset = soup.findAll('big',limit=1)


for i in continent_name_resultset:
    print((i.find(text=True).strip())[:-5])
    
list = soup.find_all('a')
for i in list:
    print(i.find(text=True))
```

My goal is to achieve this format:

```
Continent  |  Country
Africa        Algeria
Africa        Angora
          ...
          ...
```

Comment: With this code I can get all continent names and then all the subparts of it. What do you mean just the text underneath h2 tags ?  doesn't it means only word 'Africa'?

Comment: I believe your code already does this. the first for loop returns:
AFRICA
ASIA
EUROPE
N. AMERICA
OCEANIA
S. AMERICA

Comment: @OjasKale I get all the a tag from the webpage. For example Quizzes and a tags from footer. But I just want the Countrys and the continent as an Key

Comment: @ak_slick I know I just need the specific a tag = Country as an value for the continent key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the required output (for countries within `Africa` only):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://www.worldatlas.com/cntycont.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text,'lxml')
for items in soup.find_all("h2",limit=1):
    for item in items.find_next_sibling().find_all("li"):
        country = items.get_text(strip=True).split(" (")[0]
        name = item.find("a").get_text(strip=True)
        print(f'{country} {name}')
```

Output are like:

```
AFRICA Algeria
AFRICA Angola
AFRICA Benin
AFRICA Botswana
AFRICA Burkina
AFRICA Burundi
AFRICA Cameroon
AFRICA Cape Verde
```

However, if you wish to get all of them, try this:

```
url = requests.get('https://www.worldatlas.com/cntycont.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text,'lxml')
for items in soup.find_all("h2",limit=6):
    for item in items.find_next_sibling().find_all("li"):
        country = items.get_text(strip=True).split(" (")[0]
        name = item.find("a").get_text(strip=True)
        print(f'{country} {name}')
```

Comment: @SIM, there are blank lines in the output & you got the continent name wrong for S.America and N.America. Can you please fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This gives a dictionary of continent and its countries;

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://www.worldatlas.com/cntycont.htm')
html_text = url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'lxml')


mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "miscTxt"})


for tag in mydivs:
    h2Tags = tag.find_all("h2", limit=6)
    ulTags = tag.find_all("ul", limit=6)
    continents=[]
    countries = []
    for cont in h2Tags:
        continents.append(cont.text.split('(')[0].strip())

    for countrygroup in ulTags:
        temp = []
        for country in countrygroup:
            if country.find('a') != -1:
                temp.append(country.find('a').text)
        countries.append(temp)        

    final_dict=dict(zip(continents,countries))
    print final_dict
```

output is

```
{u'AFRICA': [u'Algeria',
             u'Angola',
             u'Benin',
             u'Botswana',
             u'Burkina',
             u'Burundi',
             u'Cameroon',
             u'Cape Verde',
             u'Central African Republic',
             u'Chad',
             u'Comoros',
             u'Congo',
             u'Congo, Democratic Republic of',
             u'Djibouti',
             u'Egypt',
             u'Equatorial Guinea',
             u'Eritrea',
             u'Ethiopia',
             u'Gabon',
             u'Gambia',
             u'Ghana',
             u'Guinea',
             u'Guinea-Bissau',
             u'Ivory Coast',
             u'Kenya',
             u'Lesotho',
             u'Liberia',
             u'Libya',
             u'Madagascar',
             u'Malawi',
             u'Mali',
             u'Mauritania',
             u'Mauritius',
             u'Morocco',
             u'Mozambique',
             u'Namibia',
             u'Niger',
             u'Nigeria',
             u'Rwanda',
             u'Sao Tome and Principe',
             u'Senegal',
             u'Seychelles',
             u'Sierra Leone',
             u'Somalia',
             u'South Africa',
             u'South Sudan',
             u'Sudan',
             u'Swaziland',
             u'Tanzania',
             u'Togo',
             u'Tunisia',
             u'Uganda',
             u'Zambia',
             u'Zimbabwe\n'],
 u'ASIA': [u'Afghanistan',
           u'Bahrain',
           u'Bangladesh',
           u'Bhutan',
           u'Brunei',
           u'Burma (Myanmar)',
           u'Cambodia',
           u'China',
           u'East Timor',
           u'India',
           u'Indonesia',
           u'Iran',
           u'Iraq',
           u'Israel',
           u'Japan',
           u'Jordan',
           u'Kazakhstan',
           u'Korea, North',
           u'Korea, South',
           u'Kuwait',
           u'Kyrgyzstan',
           u'Laos',
           u'Lebanon',
           u'Malaysia',
           u'Maldives',
           u'Mongolia',
           u'Nepal',
           u'Oman',
           u'Pakistan',
           u'Philippines',
           u'Qatar',
           u'Russian Federation',
           u'Saudi Arabia',
           u'Singapore',
           u'Sri Lanka',
           u'Syria',
           u'Tajikistan',
           u'Thailand',
           u'Turkey',
           u'Turkmenistan',
           u'United Arab Emirates',
           u'Uzbekistan',
           u'Vietnam',
           u'Yemen'],
 u'EUROPE': [u'Albania',
             u'Andorra',
             u'Armenia',
             u'Austria',
             u'Azerbaijan',
             u'Belarus',
             u'Belgium',
             u'Bosnia and Herzegovina',
             u'Bulgaria',
             u'Croatia',
             u'Cyprus',
             u'Czech Republic',
             u'Denmark',
             u'Estonia',
             u'Finland',
             u'France',
             u'Georgia',
             u'Germany',
             u'Greece',
             u'Hungary',
             u'Iceland',
             u'Ireland',
             u'Italy',
             u'Latvia',
             u'Liechtenstein',
             u'Lithuania',
             u'Luxembourg',
             u'Macedonia',
             u'Malta',
             u'Moldova',
             u'Monaco',
             u'Montenegro',
             u'Netherlands',
             u'Norway',
             u'Poland',
             u'Portugal',
             u'Romania',
             u'San Marino',
             u'Serbia',
             u'Slovakia',
             u'Slovenia',
             u'Spain',
             u'Sweden',
             u'Switzerland',
             u'Ukraine',
             u'United Kingdom',
             u'Vatican City'],
 u'N. AMERICA': [u'Antigua and Barbuda',
                 u'Bahamas',
                 u'Barbados',
                 u'Belize',
                 u'Canada',
                 u'Costa Rica',
                 u'Cuba',
                 u'Dominica',
                 u'Dominican Republic',
                 u'El Salvador',
                 u'Grenada',
                 u'Guatemala',
                 u'Haiti',
                 u'Honduras',
                 u'Jamaica',
                 u'Mexico',
                 u'Nicaragua',
                 u'Panama',
                 u'Saint Kitts and Nevis',
                 u'Saint Lucia',
                 u'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines',
                 u'Trinidad and Tobago',
                 u'United States'],
 u'OCEANIA': [u'Australia',
              u'Fiji',
              u'Kiribati',
              u'Marshall Islands',
              u'Micronesia',
              u'Nauru',
              u'New Zealand',
              u'Palau',
              u'Papua New Guinea',
              u'Samoa',
              u'Solomon Islands',
              u'Tonga',
              u'Tuvalu',
              u'Vanuatu'],
 u'S. AMERICA': [u'Argentina',
                 u'Bolivia',
                 u'Brazil',
                 u'Chile',
                 u'Colombia',
                 u'Ecuador',
                 u'Guyana',
                 u'Paraguay',
                 u'Peru',
                 u'Suriname',
                 u'Uruguay',
                 u'Venezuela']}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = requests.get('https://www.worldatlas.com/cntycont.htm')
html_text = url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'lxml')

continent_name_resultset = soup.select(".misc-content h2 + ul > li > a")


for i in continent_name_resultset:
    country = i.text
    continent = i.find_previous("h2").text
    continent = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z.-]","", continent)
    print("Country : " + country + " , Continent : " + continent)
```

Sample Output:

```
Country : Algeria , Continent : AFRICA
Country : Angola , Continent : AFRICA
Country : Benin , Continent : AFRICA
Country : Botswana , Continent : AFRICA
Country : Burkina , Continent : AFRICA
Country : Burundi , Continent : AFRICA
Country : Cameroon , Continent : AFRICA
Country : Cape Verde , Continent : AFRICA
Country : Central African Republic , Continent : AFRICA
Country : Chad , Continent : AFRICA
    .
    .
    .
    .
Country : Colombia , Continent : S.AMERICA
Country : Ecuador , Continent : S.AMERICA
Country : Guyana , Continent : S.AMERICA
Country : Paraguay , Continent : S.AMERICA
Country : Peru , Continent : S.AMERICA
Country : Suriname , Continent : S.AMERICA
Country : Uruguay , Continent : S.AMERICA
Country : Venezuela , Continent : S.AMERICA
```

Comment: Ty Helped a lot. I tryed everytime with find but used the wrong statement.